# Solaris 10 login - accepting multiple passwords

Tags: unix, solaris, solaris-10

I am using Oracle Solaris 10 1/3 s10x_u11wos_24a X86. When changing the password for the root account:

```
passwd
passwd: Changing password for root
passwd: password successfully changed for root
```

The password I selected was `Password!`

I can now login with `Password!` **and** `Password` - *omitting* the exclamation mark.

What is the cause of this issue? The exclamation (punctuation mark) **!** being ignored.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302419/solaris-let-me-in-with-different-password-with-the-same-8-first-characters

Comment: @AndrewHenle That answers the question. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old version of Solaris that truncated passwords to the first 8 characters. You can upgrade to Solaris 11.x.